# Removing the text only if it is between the two strings in a file using sed or python

Tags: python, bash, sed

I've to remove text between to words in a file.

1. Ex: if the two strings are hello, world and the string is  `"hey!! hello beautiful world"` ,

my expected output : `"hey!! "`.

I could achieve this using

```
re.sub('\nhello.*?world','', i , flags=re.DOTALL)
```

or using python script.

2. But, if my string is `"hey!! hello, how are you? hello beautiful world, bye"`
   my expected result is `"hey!! hello, how are you?, bye "`

How can i achieve this using sed or python.

Comment: What would the output of `foo hello there hello beautiful world this world bar` be? Does the string recursively get re-compiled and re-evaluated until no `hello.*world` exists so it first becomes `foo hello there  this world bar` and then on a second pass `foo  bar` or does it stop after the first iteration? Or does something else happen?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this negative lookahead pattern in `python` (sed doesn't support look arounds):

```
regex = re.compile(r'hello(?:(?!hello).)*?world', re.DOTALL)

str = re.sub(regex, '', str)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rO9vV2/2)

`(?:(?!hello).)*?` is negative lookahead based pattern that will match 0 or more characters (non-greedy) if `hello` is not found anywhere in the match.

Comment: this works!! but if i have to do the same thing for entire file and if the 'hello' and 'world' lies in different lines.. how is this possible..

Comment: Since I'm using `re.DOTALL` it will match it anywhere in the file across the lines.

Comment: f = open("in.txt","r")
g = open("output.txt","w")
for line in f:
 regex = re.compile(r'hello(?:(?!hello).)*?world', re.DOTALL)
 line = re.sub(regex, '', line)
 g.write(line)  
This is how i tested..it worked absolutely fine on platform though..

Answer (score 0):

sed is for simple subsitutions on individual lines, that is all. If you want to do it with a standard UNIX tool though then there's awk:

```
$ cat file
"hey!! hello beautiful world"
"hey!! hello, how are you? hello beautiful world, bye"

$ awk -v RS='world' -v ORS= 'match($0,/(.*)hello/,a){$0=a[1]}1' file
"hey!! "
"hey!! hello, how are you? , bye"
```

The above uses GNU awk for multi-char RS and the 3rd arg to match().